# "Unexpected end of input" message on response from simple POST request to node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've written a simple node.js program to demonstrate the problem I'm running into elsewhere.

Given the following node.js program:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
// simple repro for json deserializaiton error cause by right quote character '’'
var json = { 'foo': 'bar’s answer' };
var write = JSON.stringify(json);
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': write.length });
res.end(write);
}).listen(8085, '127.0.0.1');
```

When I use chrome's Advanced Rest Client to POST to this, I get back a 200 OK response, but  in the JSON tab of the response's content, the term "unexpected end of input" appears instead of the parsed json.

In the raw tab, the string "{"foo":"bar’s answer" is displayed, making it apparent why the json was unable to be parsed (it's missing the closing '}').

If I remove the '’' from the original object, the response parses just fine when it returns.

Any idea why a simple '’' causes the json to fail to be parsed?  I've ran into the same problem with various other characters in my testing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll want to set the `Content-Length` to the [`byteLength`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) instead:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(write)
});
```

As it'll differ from the `String` `length`:

```
console.log('bar’s answer'.length);             // 12
console.log(Buffer.byteLength('bar’s answer')); // 14
```

This is because, with [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) ([Node's default](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding)), they'll only match if the string consists entirely of [ASCII code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (U+0000 - U+007F), while this string contains a [U+2019](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2019), "[single curved quote, right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark_glyphs#Quotation_marks_in_Unicode)." Beyond that range, code points are expanded as needed to multiple bytes -- 3 in the case of U+2019:

```
[ 0xE2, 0x80, 0x99 ]
```

Comment: Sure enough, that seems to fix it.  Thank you, sir, you're both a scholar and a gentleman :)